# How to check latest value of standard sequence in ODI repository

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have a mapping which is using the standard sequence in ODI [Oracle Data Integrator]. I want to reset the value of that particular sequence.

It says, this standard sequence stored in repository. Not sure which repository. So could you please advise which repository [MASTER, WORK or RUN] this sequence can be able to view and modify without changing in Mapping level.

Answer (score 1):

Standard sequences are stored in the WORK and RUN repositories. I don't think you can reset them using ODI Studio.

Specific sequences are stored in a database table you specified.

Both types should be avoided where possible because they don't perform well. It is far better to use native sequences provided by your database when available.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you elaborate on the performance concerns a bit more?

Comment: If you use a Standard sequence (ODI terms here) there is interaction between a process in the target database and one in the ODI repository database. That gives lots of overhead and issues with commit consistency.

Specific sequences don't have the consistency issue, but nearly always force a row-based processing mode.

Comment: Nearly all databases have highly optimized sequence generators built in that perform much better on both aspects.